# function being displayed instead of returning a value of the data

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the realtime database from firebase and trying to retrieve the value of a specific task.
For that, I am using the on() method and adding a callback to return the value of the data but instead, it is just returning the callback function itself.

But as you can see I am logging the retrieved data ('TEST') in the console, hence there is no problem retrieving it but only returning and displaying it!

I am new to this firebase and react native so please help me out.

This my code file :

```
class TasksScreen extends Component {
  taskRef = database()
    .ref('Tasks')
    .child('D8oTrGVFNOT2Gcb7Odwf3SbbVZu2')
    .child('-LrXGvE7IBv930CX4npb')
    .child('title');

  taskTitle = this.taskRef.on('value', function(data) {
    console.log(data.val());
    return data.val();
  });
  render() {
    console.log(this.taskTitle);
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text>{this.taskTitle.toString()}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default TasksScreen;
```

[This is the terminal log:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xCI5.png)

[This is the text displayed on the screen instead of the data itself.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M2uA.png)

Comment: Can`t you just use <Text>{this.taskTitle}</Text> ?

Comment: Did you try adding a state variable for taskTitle and setting it when the callback if executed? (instead of returning the value).

Comment: Adding a state variable has solved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem is you are not calling the function . You should call function like "this.taskTitle()"**

**Please change this**

```
<Text>{this.taskTitle.toString()}</Text>
```

**to**

```
<Text>{this.taskTitle().toString()}</Text>
```